# Grails/GORM/Hibernate app is not SQL escaping input data

Tags: hibernate, grails, escaping, grails-orm, sql-injection

Our Grails/GORM-based application is not SQL-escaping string input, I can basically store any characters directly on the database.

At the same time everyone says that GORM/Hibernate takes care of escaping input automatically.

Is there some configuration option or a combination of plugins known to disable automatic escaping?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your post to contain an example query? It is possible you are incorrectly using Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The question incorrectly assumes that SQL escaping should happen before inserting data to database. Instead GORM/Hibernate [escapes data](http://Grails%20Security%20Docs) when constructing SQL queries and binding parameter values and that is how it prevents [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29).